# Fragments. ActionBar Back navigation

Tags: android, navigation, android-actionbar-compat, fragment-backstack

I have one Activity and three Fragments. When I go from one fragment to another I write it transaction into backStack:

```
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

When I press back arrow on ActionBar and go to the first fragment that arrow is lose and it's right.

```
 switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:

           FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            OfficialNameFragment offName = new OfficialNameFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.remove(offName);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar()
.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

```
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

But if I press system back button and go to the first fragment that back arrow is stay and it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

when I override system back button in Activity like that

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    super.onBackPressed();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
}
```

back arrow is lose when I go from third to second fragments.
But it is necessary that the arrow disappears when the transition from the second to the first fragment.